# Advanced file system search with Python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

I'd like to create a Python script that will make some file searches recursively based on extension and file date. The most simple way (to me) to specify the requirements is this SQL like statement:

```
select filedate, count(*) from 'c:\folder\*' 
where filename like '%.txt'
group by filedate
```

Any ideas on what is the simpliest solution?

Comment: `filedate` meaning created, last modified, accessed, what? Look at `glob` for getting filenames, and the `os` module for checking dates.

Comment: filedate like created

Answer (score 0):

You will have to piece a solution together from Python's various facilities.

I like to use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for traversing a file system recursively.

[`os.path.getctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) can get the creation time (as epoch time) of a given file. You can use the time module to get the date from there.

I would use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) to link dates to lists of files.